# IE 11 fetched form input bug

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, fetch

I think this ist kind of a very special Bug and I hope you might help me.
First my setup:

I'm using ES6 in my web project and I'm loading a form with fetch into an overlay. Everything works fine until I try to fill out my input fields. The inputs seem to loose the focus but I used `document.activeElement` and the input was correctly focussed. The cursor is lost and that's precisely the problem.

[image]

The arrow shows the cursor which is definitely not in the input.

All browsers work fine (even in IE10 the problem is't available).

To prevent Internet Explorer 11 issues with ES6 I use the [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) and no errors appear in that browser.

I removed all of my CSS to exclude the possibility of damaging css and I removed nearly all of my JS instead of my fetch call.

```
fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'}).then(function (response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    return response.text();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  }).then(function (body) {
    let div = document.createElement('div'), content;
    $(div).html(body);
    content = div.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
    overlay.querySelectorAll('.content-wrapper')[0].appendChild(content);
});
```

the `overlay` is my previous added DOM object where I wanted to insert my fetched form.

My only explanation is the issue between IE11 and ES6 and even the babel-polyfill couldn't fix this.

Anybody else with that kind of experience? I hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: add some `console.log` statements in your code - do they get called?

Comment: I tried keydown and got an event fired but the input value didn't change

Comment: Found the problem. I added the overlay to document.documentElement. If the overlay is added to document.body everything works fine - someone there who understands IE11 logic?